# Google charts, alternative stacked column chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to be able to create a graph showing a top 5 per day in a week.

The graph I'm trying to mimic look like this:

[image: Top Graph]
So my problem with the google charts api is that I cannot find a way to for each day to contain possibly different headers.

I hope you are able to help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is to have your code assign a style for each category/header you have and then add the the appropriate style after each piece of data using `role: 'style'` columns. Your data rows would look something like:

```
   ['Monday', 77, 'color: red', 50, 'color: gray', 18, 'color: green', 10, 'color: pink', 3, 'color: black'],
   ['Tuesday', 99, 'color: blue', 83, 'color: green', 66, 'color: red', 25, 'color: black', 7, 'color: pink'],
```

Although you could style in additional ways to just color.

Here is a fiddle with two sets, not five, but you should be able to get the idea. 
http://jsfiddle.net/y80o9uq1/3/

If this does not answer your question, please add some more information about the kind of data you are working with. This solution would not  be good if there are thousands of categories, but could work with tens, or possibly hundreds.

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you very much. Exactly how I imagined the api should work. Thank you so much. I found the DataTable Roles and has been able to implement the view as I needed.